# Identification of Lego bags with large tan plates, white cylindrical panels, palm leaves and yellow ladders

Tags: set-identification

Can someone help me to identify which set is this from?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Lime plant leaves 6x5 Swordleaf](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10884&idColor=34), [Tan plate 8x8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41539&idColor=2), [Tan plate round half 3x6 with 1x2 cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18646&idColor=2), and [Trans-light blue panel 3x4x6 Curved top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2571&idColor=15), this set has to be [41374-1 Andrea's Pool Party](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41374-1).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's the one!